# how to change axios encoding for query in koa app?

Tags: javascript, encoding, axios, koa

When sending an axios request in my Koa app, one of my query parameters has brackets as so:
`lastTenDays:[now-10d TO now]`.

Here is the request:

```
const response = await this.axiosInstance.get('/somePath', {
      params: {
        query: query
        offset: 0,
        limit: 20,
        count: true
      }
    })
```

When I print the response.request, I notice there's an axios field `_currentUrl` which shows the path of the request. In this case, it looks like this:
`https://myBaseUrl.com/somePath?query=lastTenDays:[now-10d+TO+now]&offset=0&limit=20&count=true`

Here's what's weird. If I encode my query parameter like this: `lastTenDays:%5Bnow-10d+TO+now%5D`, the `_currentUrl` doesn't change at all!

It seems that when the brackets aren't encoded, they don't get encoded, and when they are encoded, they are decoded on the request. What's going on? How can I prevent this so I can send the encoded brackets in th request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out axios does some weird stuff. Checkout their code here https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/helpers/buildURL.js#L5, and you can see they have a custom encode function that, among other things, unencodes brackets to their plaintext value.

```
replace(/%5B/gi, '[').
replace(/%5D/gi, ']');
```

This was why whether I passed %5B or '[' to the endpoint, axios always converted it to '['.

**The solution**:
One can specify a custom param serializer using `paramsSerializer` in the request configuration laid out here: https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config.

For example, this could look like:

```
const querystring = require('querystring')
const response = await this.axiosInstance.get('/somePath', {
      params: {
        query: query
        offset: 0,
        limit: 20,
        count: true
      },
     paramsSerializer: querystring.stringify
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, one hacky way to fix this is by running `decodeURI` & `encodeURI` like this -

```
const oldUrl = 'https://myBaseUrl.com/somePath?query=lastTenDays:[now-10d+TO+now]&offset=0&limit=20&count=true';
const newUrl = encodeURI(decodeURI(oldUrl));
```

Comment: This won't help. The issue is after the request is executed `lastTenDays:[now-10d+TO+now]` or `lastTenDays:%5Bnow-10d+TO+now%5D` is getting converted to `lastTenDays:[now-10d+TO+now]`

Comment: even if I hard code lastTenDays:%5Bnow-10d+TO+now%5D it won't work